wireshark on ubuntu wsl
enter image description here
(wireshark:7282) 06:45:32.501138 [GUI WARNING] -- could not connect to display :1.0
(wireshark:7282) 06:45:32.501245 [GUI ERROR] -- This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
